# Linux Nginx + php-fpm + cron + mysqld = always out of memory

Tags: linux, mysql, cron, memory, php-fpm

I don't get it. I have a VPS with Nginx and php-fpm and MySQL. Should be very lightweight. No Apache, right? When I reboot, it is very lightweight. ~ 50/481 MB MEM usage. Very acceptable IMO.

And after a few days there are ~ 20 mysqld processes running and ~ 7 php-fpm processes and ~ 8 getty processes and 3/4 of 1024 MB swap full and the server is out of memory!

I'm not a pro, but I'm pretty sure that's not right...

I think the crons have something to do with it. I have 3 jobs scheduled:

- a simple one (read smtp for new mail) every minute
- a big one (read RSS from ~ 30 blogs) every night
- a simple one (mysqldump of 2 small databases) every morning

I'm not sure why I think that =) Probably because the simple job (SMTP, every minute) is always in the htop list. (But always with 0% cpu, 0% mem and 0:00:00 time...)

The 20 mysqld's are also very strange, but they don't seem to require a lot of memory.

The php-fpm's apparently do consume a lot of memory. In the 10 minutes it took to write this, the mem has gone from 66 MB to 120 MB! The top 6 mem consuming processes are `php-fpm: pool www`. When I restart `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` the mem goes down to ~ 70 MB. How does php-fpm require 400+ MB of mem? What's up with that?

Swap has been pretty steady at ~ 98 MB the last 10 mins.

Anyone know what might be going on? (I know it's very little info on a whole server.) I can add details if you wish.

I'm not even running any decent sized websites!

**More info:**

A screen of `htop --sort-key PERCENT_MEM`: [image: htop]

Pastebin with `ps xv`, `cat /proc/meminfo` and `top`: http://pastebin.com/PfXeupMN

Comment: Can you post few iterations of top, ps -xv and a snapshot of /proc/meminfo in some pastebin link. Also, if you can show the oom messages it will be more clear.

Comment: Can you paste your php-fpm pool configuration, as well as you mysql configuration.

Also, it might be a good idea to run mysqltuner perl script and paste its output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong in the server config (very very slow i/o) that was to blame. The vps provider did a hardware update (I think) and it was all fixed. Mem usage might still be high (I don't know) but overall the server is super fast again.

Sorry I didn't mention this before.